# Is support for a specific program OK here - under what conditions?

Tags: discussion

Since some time I'm using [Subtitle edit](http://www.nikse.dk/subtitleedit/). The author, Nikolaj Lynge Olsson, has a very decent help file on his site. Despite that, people of course still have questions (I just mailed him one).
You can email him, he'll answer sooner or later (I don't know how fast, usually), and I have also seen the occasional answer from him on miscellaneous forums.

*I'm thinking of suggesting him to take his support to SU*.
That way he would only have to check one site for questions, other people can contribute as well, and the answers benefit more people at once.

- Is this OK here? (I don't see anything in help or meta against it, and there are many program-specific tags already)
- Are there any special requirements?

And we would need a tag, of course (<kbd>subtitle-edit</kbd>?)

Comment: Relevant: [Is it okay to use Stack Overflow as the support forum for a product or project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3966)

Comment: When I read the question, my initial reaction was that this just seemed inappropriate, that it would be a bad precedent, and that there was potential for abuse and unanticipated problems.  Then I read the link in DavidPostill's comment and see that this has been thoroughly discussed there, including issues I hadn't thought of.  It's fine for the developers to refer appropriate questions here, but I agree with the discussion in the link that we should not become the official support site for any product.

Comment: We are not that type of site.  If he wants to offer support for his program he can pay for his own website.  An author doesn't "bring their support" to Superuser.  I don't agree this would be good for Superuser

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is go ahead and ask your question about Subtitle Edit on the main Superuser site. As long as you stick to the topic guidelines in the help center, you should have no problems. (Specifically, avoid asking "What software can I use to do X?" -- for that, look over at [softwarerecs.stackexchange.com](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)).

As long as your question is about some feature/functionality of Subtitle Edit, feel free to ask your question. You may not get answers from the author, but other people might know about it too and be able to help. You can then link the author to your question.